# HP IRF and number of access switches

Tags: hp

Is there a limitation in the number of access switches can be connected to HP 10xxx in the core with IRF configuration?

Comment: I think you should ask HP directly.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine a maximum of 4 x 10500 switches in an IRF cluster.